# Lightweight jax-rs client

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Using below code sample from tutorial i can successfully make post to a jax-rs service on glassfish-4.

```
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();
WebTarget root = client.target("http://localhost:8080/roast-house/api/coffeebeans");
Bean origin = new Bean("arabica", RoastType.DARK, "mexico");
final String mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
final Entity<Bean> entity = Entity.entity(origin, mediaType);
Response response = root.request().post(entity, Response.class);
response.close();
```

But it forces to bring a dependency that totals about 4.5mb (resteasy 3.0.5 was ~5mb)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the feeling i'm using only a portion of the client API, is there any more lightweight clients out there, or how would i go about to construct the request using only standard libraries?

Comment: Do you need a client that unterstands REST or is a simple HTTP client enough?

Comment: on the other side there is a jax-rs service that consumes the bean. So i need to xml-ify in the proper way and the comply with what a jax-rs service expects from clients